# pip3 installation error with the iconservice package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

I am trying to `$ sudo pip3 install iconservice` as instructed in this tutorial: 
https://medium.com/@2infiniti/creating-icon-dapp-from-a-z-part-1-tools-environment-dd56f8dfc905.

I'm running OS-X.

I am receiving the following error message and I am not sure what's going on. I have messed around with cflags as instructed elsewhere but nothing changes.

```
35 warnings and 4 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

```
  Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plyvel-1.1.0.dist-info/
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~lyvel-1.1.0.dist-info
  Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plyvel/
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~lyvel
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-nsgaksl0/plyvel/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-rhqla4_4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-nsgaksl0/plyvel/~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `iconservice` package [requires `libsecp256k`](https://github.com/icon-project/icon-service#requirements) to be installed on your system.

```
Building wheel for secp256k1 (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: ...
ERROR: 0.29.1
Using bundled libsecp256k1
...
Failed to build secp256k1
```

For Linux, simply install it first by following the [Setup on Linux](https://github.com/icon-project/icon-service#setup-on-linux) steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libleveldb1 libleveldb-dev libsecp256k1-dev
$ pip install iconservice
```

For Mac OS X, it requires a bit more steps:

```
# install leveldb
$ brew install pkg-config automake libtool leveldb

# install libsecp256k (from source)
# based on this (https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1#build-steps)
$ git clone https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1.git
$ cd secp256k1/
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make

# install plyvel
# based on this (https://github.com/wbolster/plyvel/issues/66#issuecomment-460094085)
$ mv /Applications/XCode.app /Applications/Xcode_cp.app
$ leveldb_version=$(ls /usr/local/Cellar/leveldb/ | tail -1)
$ CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++" \
pip install plyvel \
--no-cache-dir \
--global-option=build_ext \
--global-option="-I/usr/local/Cellar/leveldb/${leveldb_version}/include/" \
--global-option="-L/usr/local/lib"
$ mv /Applications/XCode_cp.app /Applications/Xcode.app
$ pip freeze | grep plyvel
plyvel==1.1.0

# download icon-service source
$ git clone https://github.com/icon-project/icon-service.git

# edit the requirements.txt included with the icon-service source
# to update the plyvel version to match what's already installed
# on your machine (from the previous step)
$ cd icon-service
$ vim requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
    ...
    plyvel==1.1.0  <-- I updated this from 1.0.5
    ...

# build and install iconservice from wheels
$ ./build.sh
$ CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++" \
pip install dist/iconservice-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl \
--no-cache-dir \
--global-option=build_ext \
--global-option="-I/usr/local/Cellar/leveldb/${leveldb_version}/include/" \
--global-option="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

Note that I installed `iconservice` from source, because `pip install iconservice` still fails (I think the wheel is not built properly for Mac OS X). Then I also updated the `plyvel` version in the *requirements.txt* file from the `iconservice` source, because installing it from the wheel expects the 1.0.5 version but I already had plyvel at 1.1.0 (I don't know if that's going to have an effect on the package's behavior..).

---

On a side note, if you're already using a virtual environment, you should not be using `sudo` anymore with `pip install`. The purpose of using a virtualenv is to avoid "dirtying" the system packages, if you use `sudo` it kind of defeats the purpose of the virtualenv.

Comment: Hey Gino thanks for your response. I forgot to say, I'm using OSX. These dependencies don't seem to be available to install with Homebrew. Any idea how I go about this?

Point taken on the virtualenv. Thanks!

Comment: I've installed the 
'$ brew install leveldb autoconf automake pkg-config libtool libffi gmp' dependencies as instructed btw

Comment: @user1893110 You're right, `libsecp256k` is not available from Homebrew, but you could install it from [source](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1). But there are still some problems with `pip install iconservice` after... I'm trying to install it on my Mac, but it's a bit more problematic. Give me a moment. :)

Comment: @user1893110 I updated my answer for the successful installation steps for Mac OS X :)

Comment: Didn't get the chance to log on til now but thank you so much for these thorough instructions :) I'll give em a try in a bit